# Can I point to Wolfram's geoserver from outside Mathematica?

Tags: geographics

Sadly, I'm having to port my Mathematica code. I'd like to use the same (or very similar) GeoGraphics default map background as my Mathematica code does.  Can I somehow point to and use Wolfram's geoserver for map tiles?

Alternately, where does Mathematica get its map backgrounds from? Maybe I could point back to this source instead...

Comment: This looks like something you should be asking Support, but I am not sure WRI will be cool with you using *Mathematica*'s tiles with a non-*Mathematica* application.